# How to prevent .tmp being added to temp files using PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, gd

When saving temp files (when uploading files) on Linux using PHP, the files are saved as /tmp/phpKdnFKk for example. There is no file extension.

Doing the same on Windows, .tmp will be added to temp files.

How do I prevent this from happening? I want the same behavior as on Linux: no .tmp on the temp files.

Reason? PHP's GD extension can't overwrite the temp file. It breaks due to the .tmp. The library thinks it's an invalid image type, only due to the file extension.

UPDATE: without moving and saving the file somewhere else . I know that would work, but you also lose the 'auto delete when script finishes' feature of temp files.

Final update:
You shouldn't manually overwrite tmp files that PHP creates of uploaded files.

Comment: Just move and rename it somewhere else.

Comment: Why does it matter what they're named? You shouldn't even need to know what the file name is, you just work with the `tmpfile` file handle until you've done what you need and then the file is cleaned up. NOTHING should overwrite a temp file; if you have derivative data that needs to temporarily be a file, you create a _new_ temp file to have that cleaned up as well. That said, GD doesn't even need file writes, it can work entirely in memory, so you're going to have to explain why you need it to write to temp files at all. And some [MCVE] code would probably help here, too.

Comment: We do additional processing on the uploaded image even after GD was used to manipulate it. The idea was that we keep the file temporary, until we know all processing and validation was passed.
But you convinced me that is a wrong way of handling it. We'll simply move the file, and move on from there.